# ElasticSearch sort by field

Tags: elasticsearch

i have this query:

```
 GET /_search
    {
    "from" : 0, "size" : 30,
    "query": {
    "filtered": { 
       "query" : {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "((categoria.id:1752) AND (cidadeId:7300)) 
           OR ((categoria.id:1752) and (estadoId:13)) "
        }
      }
    }
    },
    "sort": [
        { "img":   { "order": "desc" } }
    ]
 }
```

I would like to order by cidadeId = 7300 and then the other but do not know how to do this in the sort

Answer (score 0):

I have considered a small example :

```
PUT test/test/1
{
  "categoria.id":1752,
  "cidadeId":7300
}

PUT test/test/2
{
  "categoria.id":1752,
  "estadoId":13
}

PUT test/test/3
{
  "categoria.id":175,
  "cidadeId":1
  "estadoId":13
}
```

With the few information you are giving in your answer, I can give you the following solution for ascendant sorting on cidadeId

```
GET test/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 30,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "((categoria.id:1752) AND (cidadeId:7300)) OR ((categoria.id:1752) and (estadoId:13))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "cidadeId": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I hope this will help

Comment: Sorry, I think I was not clear enough. I would first bring the records where the cidadeId equals 1752 (as an example), then the other cidadeId's. It would be something like: ORDER BY field (cidade_id ...

Comment: You are still not clear. Can you please provide a concrete example? Add your example to the question!